# Getting Braintree client token using PHP?

Tags: php, eclipse, google-app-engine, braintree

I'm following Braintree's instructions to create a client token using [this page](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/android+php/start/hello-server#provide-a-client-token-to-your-client).

I made a Sandbox Account. Then, I downloaded the PHP library. The file downloaded as `braintree-php-2.37.0.tgz`, which I unzipped.

Then, using Eclipse for PHP Developers and following [these directions](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/adding_a_php_library.htm), I:

- went to `Eclipse`, then `Preferences...`, then `PHP`, then `Libraries`, then `New...`
- made a new library called `braintree`
- chose `Add External folder...` and added the `braintree-php-2.37.0` folder which I had earlier unzipped.
- went to the `Properties` of the app I'm working on
- went to `PHP`, then `Include Path`, then `Libraries`, then `Add Library...`
- then chose `User Library` and clicked `Next >`, then selected `braintree` (which I had just made) and clicked `Finish`
- finalized by clicking `OK`

After I've done all of the above, I see that within the project's `PHP Include Path` folder, `braintree` is present with `Braintree.php` and all.

I then continued with the first set of instructions and my PHP file basically looks like this:

```
Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('<my_merchant_id>');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('<my_public_key>');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('<my_private_key>');

$clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate();
```

But nothing happens. It seems like the code won't even get past `Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');`.

I see in many places that `require_once 'PATH_TO_BRAINTREE/lib/Braintree.php';` is included but I don't know how to write the path to the Braintree.php file. I added the actual path which leads to where I downloaded the Braintree folder, but that didn't help at all. And I'm also further confused because I figured that Braintree.php is already added as a library.

I'm also using Google App Engine and uploading my PHP code to their server. I'm not sure if this is part of the problem or not.

**EDIT:**

I took the unzipped folder (`braintree-php-2.37.0`) and copied it into the PHP folder so it could be uploaded to Google App Engine as well.

I then edited my PHP code to be this:

```
<?php

require_once('./braintree-php-2.37.0/lib/Braintree.php');

Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('<my_merchant_id>');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('<my_public_key>');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('<my_private_key>');

$clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate();

?>
```

The code now won't get past `require_once('./braintree-php-2.37.0/lib/Braintree.php');`.

Comment: You'll need to upload the `Braintree.php` file too, and anything else it may require, as "part of your GAE app": e.g if you make a subdirectory `bt` of your main app directory and unzip the whole bt zip with that as root, then `./bt` will also be the value to substitute for `PATH_TO_BRAINTREE` above.

Comment: Thanks, @Alex Martelli, your suggestion made sense. But something's still wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately I know too little PHP to help, but, is there a specific error message/traceback you're getting?

Comment: I also know very little PHP. PHP tends to crash silently and I don't know how to explicitly force it to print out error messages.

Comment: Ah!-(  I live by the Zen of Python -- "Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced." -- which may explain why I know so little PHP... sorry!-(

Comment: I know what you mean. :\

Comment: @user2323030 I work at Braintree. This seems like something that's going to need some back-and-forth to solve, so I'd suggest you [reach out to the Braintree Support Team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussing the details over with the staff from Braintree, we've come to the conclusion that, at the present moment, Google App Engine using PHP will not play nicely with Braintree's setup.

Hopefully there will be an answer to this problem in the future.

Comment: Any update on this on Braintree integration with GAE?